Sparse Cross Entropy
I've been attempting to mess around with Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy Loss for the MNIST dataset. I can't seem to figure out what might be wrong with my implementation, the loss seems to erroneously shoot up.
I figure this to be the correct formula?
$CE_{sparse} = - \frac{1}{m} \sum y_{integerencoded} * \log{\hat{Y}}$ , where $m$ is the number of samples
The model was working normally with Categorical Cross Entropy (with one_hot_encodings), but when I introduce integer encodings instead, things seem to blow up.
I'm curious to know, what might be wrong with my implementation?
# Y IS THE ORIGINAL MNIST LABELS, A2 IS THE RAW SOFTMAX OUTPUT.

def sparse_cc_loss(y, a2):
    eps = 1e-10
    l = - np.sum(y * np.log(a2 + eps)) / 60000
    return l

If you might need more reference, check out the github repo here
Not sure if it's the calculation of $\frac{∂CE_{sparse}}{∂z_2}$ which might be playing a factor.
I did so as:
dz2 = a2 - y, where y are the MNIST labels (0-9), and a2is the raw softmax output.

So class 0 has loss $− 0 \log \hat y=0$
and class 9 has loss $−9 \log \hat y$
? This is clearly not correct.
The correct implementation takes as input a vector $\hat y$  with 10 elements and you want to select the $k$th element from it, where $k$ is the correct class: $-\log \hat {y}_k$
